# Beginner html/css: Why does my webpage distort when I comment out the universal borders?

Tags: html, css

I'm just playing around with HTML/CSS at the moment and my goal at the moment is to move my table to the top center of the page. When I turn the universal borders on, I can move it to exactly where I want it to but as soon as I comment it out, the table jumps elsewhere!

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Triangle-Shiny-Modern-Background-.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

* #move {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.profile {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

iframe {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

form {
  clear: left;
}

#nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Cursive;
}

#times table {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: -600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/*table {
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
     }*/

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Store</li>
    <li>About me</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<img id="move" src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/16425751_1848826525393050_4826825314980823096_n.jpg?oh=1228198713ee79012631342e3bb4b650&oe=596D7646" width="300" height="300" align="left">
<div class="profile">
  <h2>Samuel Wu</h2>
  <p>Age: 24</p>
  <p>Sex: Male</p>
  <p>Height: 5'7</p>

</div>

<iframe width="320" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zCUlm9F-P9E?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<form>
  <h3> What do you think about Samuel Wu?</h3>
  <input type="text" value="just fk me up fam">
  <p>Did you answer honestly?<input type="checkbox"></p>
  <h3>How well do you think you know Samuel Wu?</h3>
  <p>What is his favorite color?</p>
  <select>
        <option>red</option>
        <option>blue</option>
        <option>green</option>
       </select>
  <p><input type="submit" value="$5 to submit"></p>
</form>
<div id="times">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>x</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "universal borders" ?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I think he's referring to this rule: `* {
  border: 2px solid black;
}`

Comment: A couple of things about borders will affect layout. First, the width of the border adds to the width/height of the element in the normal `content-box` box model. Second, [margins often collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and adding a border keeps margins from collapsing.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Ah that kind of makes sense to me. Removing the border means that margins can collapse...thanks for the input

Comment: @spamwoo np. lemme know if you'd like me to submit it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker So instead of addressing the problem directly, I went around it. I changed the color of the universal border to "transparent" and everything stays where I'd like them to but I feel like this might be the wrong approach to web development and design. This ended up with me having a white border around the entire webpage which looks pretty bad...I created a new div for the entire body with a border which doesn't actually fill in the white area but instead created a new border within between the border and content (which I kind of like!).

Comment: spamwoo, I'd suggest you don't use them if you are using them transparent, you will still have undesired behavior while not even using them "visually".

Comment: @syden I agree, going around the problem seems to be the wrong approach. If you guys can guide me with a hint that would be helpful too!

Comment: @spamwoo lol yeah that's definitely the wrong approach :) But you're learning and trying stuff and that's awesome. You don't want to apply borders like that just to avoid margin collapse, and you certainly don't want borders around everything on your site. You shouldn't use a huge negative margin to position things like that, either.

Comment: @spamwoo, I added a suggestion in the answer to avoid the `negative-margin`, hope helps. Regards.

Comment: @Syden Thanks! I like that absolute position fix!

Comment: @Syden You got it bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are giving every element borders and these borders generate extra space and will push other elements. Unless you actually plan to use borders on everything, your best bet would be to either tweak `margin` values of the `table` with only the borders that are going to be used, or none at all.

If you comment/remove borders, you can tweak `#times table`'s negative `margin-top` to something like `550px` which should position the table pretty similar to when all borders are set.

**Without** borders:

[image]

**With** borders:

[image]

Alternative to avoid negative margin-top:

- Use `position: absolute;` which will make the `table` independent from the rest of the elements flow, and tweak `top` & `left` values to your benefit:

Example:

[image]